# Remove both duplicate items (if one is duplicate) from a list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How can I remove the duplicate item and the other item which was compared with the duplicate one from a List using Linq. Following is the query:

```
var test = myList
  .GroupBy(x => x.WHEN)
  .Select(y => y.First())
  .ToList();
```

Here list is already sorted and WHEN refers to DateTime. This is what I want to achieve.

```
01.01.2018 08:00:00 --> should be removed
01.01.2018 08:00:00 --> should be removed
01.01.2018 08:10:00
01.01.2018 08:11:00
02.01.2018 08:00:45 --> should be removed
02.01.2018 08:00:45 --> should be removed
```

Comment: Use Distinct() method

Comment: @Satpal this will not solve op's issue see he wants to remove those elements which are duplicate and dont want even single element of it

Comment: @Satpal this won't remove all duplicates.

Comment: `var test = myList.GroupBy(x => x.WHEN).Where(group => group.Count() == 1).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's filter by group size (we want groups with *one* item only):

```
 var test = myList
   .GroupBy(x => x.WHEN)
   .Where(group => group.Count() == 1) // single item groups only
   .Select(group => group.First())
   .ToList();
```

Comment: `!group.Skip(1).Any()` would be more efficient

Comment: @arekzyla For what LINQ provider?

Comment: @arekzyla: No: in case of `GroupBy` it would not be more efficient since `GroupedEnumerable` (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7adf36498ee1fe7a,references) has `Count` as a simple property

Comment: @DmitryBychenko True, but using LINQ one shouldn't think or even know anything about implementation details because it's declarative language so on this level of abstraction my expression should be more efficient (less iterations). Consider OP want's to change it to `group.Where(...).Count()`

Answer (score 1):

you can try below linq code :

```
myList.GroupBy(x => x.WHEN)
      .Where(x => x.Any(xEle => myList.Where(ele => ele == xEle))
      .Count() == 1)
      .ToList();
```

Comment: I didn't, but what's the point of `.Distinct` if you already have only those whose `.Count() == 1`?

Comment: not my downvote but I tried your approach but nothing happend.

Comment: `myList.Where(ele => ele == x)` is comparing `T` to groups of `T`.